# Convert array of dicts to JSON file to graph with flot

Tags: python, json, formatting, flot

I am taking readings from 4 sensors. I get an array like this:

```
[{"value":0.162512,"number":0,"channel":0},
 {"value":0.027835,"number":1,"channel":1},
 {"value":0.08361,"number":2,"channel":2},
 {"value":0.295788,"number":3,"channel":3},
 {"value":0.137746,"number":4,"channel":0},
 {"value":0.009403,"number":5,"channel":1},
 {"value":0.089616,"number":6,"channel":2},
 {"value":0.310242,"number":7,"channel":3},
 {"value":0.109047,"number":8,"channel":0},
 ...
 {"value":0.085652,"number":28,"channel":0},
 {"value":0.01359,"number":29,"channel":1},
 {"value":0.105441,"number":30,"channel":2},
 {"value":0.32407,"number":31,"channel":3}]
```

I need to format and convert it into a JSON object, I guess from reading through here. I then will use flot to draw a graph. That is the goal.

I want a line graph, showing each reading off of the four sensors. I will be using this in Python eventually if that helps the direction I am going.

I have no clue what I am doing, so any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be my guardian angel! I needed this piece done today. THANK YOU for helping me!!!! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Having no clue is not a good starting point ... See the flot [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) and [examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/) to get started.

What you have there is one array of objects. (Already as JSON from the looks of it. If that is still on the python side, put it as a string in your javascript and call `JSON.parse()` on it, it is already valid JSON.)

What you need is an array of arrays (dataseries) of arrays (datapoints). Something like

```js
[
    [ // dataseries for channel 0
        [0, 0.162515],
        [4, 0.137746],
        ...
    ],
    [ // dataseries for channel 1
        [1, 0.027835],
        [5, 0.009403],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

To convert you can loop over your original array and put the datapoints in the right dataseries with something like this:

```js
var dataAsArrays = [
    [], [], [], [] // one empty array for each dataseries / channel
];
$.each(dataAsObjects, function (index, item) {
    dataAsArrays[item.channel].push([item.number, item.value]);
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gza5egL/) for a working example of the above code.